# why Spring Security Exception Translation Filter creates 403 Response Code for default configuration

Tags: spring-security

I am pretty new to Spring Security land. I am using programmatic configuration of Spring Security with `servletApi()` which is pretty neat.

Here is the configuration:

```
  @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
         .securityContext().and()
         .servletApi().and()
         .authorizeUrls()
         .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
   }
```

I am using http servlet api login I am not using any filter for this.

In case a unauthorised request, `ExceptionTranslationFilter` uses `Http403EntryForbiddenEntryPoint` to return 403 forbidden status.

In my scenario:

1. If user does not authenticated, a 401 status code should return.
2. If user authenticated but not authorised, a 403 status code should return.

But default configuration creates 403 status for both case.

Here are my questions:

1. Why is the default entry point is `Http403EntryForbiddenEntryPoint`? It can be 401?
2. If I change Http`403`EntryForbiddenEntryPoint to Http`401`EntryForbiddenEntryPoint, does It create a problem?

Thanks